# Can I refer to columns in another table for validation rule in MS access2000?

Tags: database, ms-access

I want to design the table `[students]`, with column `"stduent ID","Class Type", "Name"`

I also already have table `[Class]`, with column `"Class Type", "maximum students"`

I want to set the rule as:

`[students]."student ID" < [Class]."maximum students"` for a certain `"Class Type"`.

Is it possible to do it in the validation rules when designing tables in MS access2000?

Comment: A student ID has to be less than maximum students? Huh?

Comment: I wrote a little here under community additions http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb177889(v=office.12).aspx